# Overlaying Action Bar - Android Studio Tutorial

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overlay

Run into a small problem while working with the Android tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

I have created a custom action bar theme where the android:windowActionBarOverlay property has been set to true.

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

I then applied this theme to the entire application in the manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"  >
```

The problem then was that the bar was covering parts of the app that needed to remain visible. I added the following as the app said and it fixed the first view (where you type in a message and hit send)

```
android:paddingTop="attr/actionBarSize"
```

However the following activity, which is supposed to display the message, is still covered by the action bar. I want to know where I add the top padding so that I can fix this view as well.
I did a little searching and found that the layout for this 'display message' activity was defined in the .java file 
(Atleast I think it is)

```
//Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    //Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
```

I tried doing a textView.setPadding() but that function only takes ints as arguments so I can't pass something like "attr/actionBarSize"

To reiterate: Need help figuring out where the layout for the display message activity is and how I can edit it so that I can set the Top padding just as I did for the main view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ActionBar height as an int:

```
int actionBarHeight = 0;

TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
    actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

And you can use that value to `setPadding()` or `setMargins()`.

Or you can add the top margin/padding to your second activity layout file, but it's hard to help without looking at the code or the xml layout files of the activities.

Comment: Where do I define this integer and how do I pass it to the second activity's class?

So the reason I'm confused is that in the tutorial, (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) they ask you to create a layout for the second activity called activity_display_message but then use textView as the layout instead. That's the reason I didn't put the 2nd layout's xml in my question because it's a default "Hello World!" file.

Comment: Define it directly in the activity in which you need to use it.

P.s. Usually you create a class and a layout for every activity, you combine them with  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)`, and then change the components of the layout in the java code. So, just create a layout for the second activity, use `android:paddingTop="attr/actionBarSize"` where you need it, and you're done.

Comment: Put your code in the onCreate() function and it works perfectly, thank you so much. Thanks for the tip as well; it's just that I was following the tutorial and I think they use the TextView widget for the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this exact same problem following the Android tutorial. The above answer by Jones fixes the problem, but here is a way to use `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` in the layout xml file for the Display Message activity.

If you follow the tutorial [Starting Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage) and [Add Up Button for Low-level Activities](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav), you will end up with `/java/com.something.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java` like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaymessage);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

The code above creates a new TextView that is beyond the scope of the layout file for this activity. Instead, what you want to do is reuse the "Hello World" TextView that has already been declared in the `/res/layout/activity_display_message.xml` file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="my.vstore.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add an id to the TextView `android:id="@+id/display_message"` and then change the paddingTop to `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="my.vstore.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity">

<TextView android:id="@+id/display_message"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then, find the id of the TextView and set the Text in `/java/com.something.myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaymessage);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Find the text view
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_message);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

Thus, you can use `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` in the layout xml file for the Display Message activity.